# electron packager not packaging darwin version correctly

Tags: packaging, electron

I am trying to package my app with electron-packager. For a start , running my electron works fine and easy with the

```
electron .
```

I then install electron-packager and attempted to package with my command belwo

```
electron-packager . app --out ./electron --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --version=0.35.0 --overwrite
```

It packaged only 3 files in my folder. The app, the licence and the version files. When i click the app, it throws error cannot find module .../...electron.js. When i change my command to

```
electron-packager . app --out ./electron --platform=win32 --arch=x64 --version=0.35.0 --overwrite
```

it works fine and packaged with all the folders and files i was expecting. I tried everything possible yet couldn't get it to package the darwin version with the resource folders and necessary files. It is failing as a result. Please what causes this and how do i resolved it please? Any help would be appreciated.

Note:  I am running OSX ELCAPITAN version 10.11.4 on my machine.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: i used electron-builder insttead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to package it on version 0.35, have you tried to package a newer version? Try that.

Comment: @willib321 i tried --version=1.2.1 and --version=1.2.2 which are the two latest versions at the moment. They both failed.

Comment: Is your electron packager up to date? Try running without the version flag.

Comment: @willib321. My app is running --version1.2.1 and i ran it as u suggested , yet nothing change. I am confused actually. The problem persist. Have done everything to my understanding .

Comment: Yah i currently have 1.2.2 installed . I run without the --version as you suggested .

Comment: have you tried running `npm install` and then packaging? @NuruSalihu

Comment: @wilyb321 thanks for the help man. It does not work . I tried , i tried everything all to no avail .

Comment: @NuruSalihu Sorry I couldn't help buddy, thanks for upvoting and all that. :)

Comment: @willby321 nope you did help a lot.It works , thank you for your time .

Comment: @NuruSalihu well, glad I could help then!